# Unable to return correct vales searching in Java Swing program using SQL Operators

Tags: java, sqlite, swing

I have created a Java Swing desktop app program that calls SQLite and I would like it to perform a search functionality based on some user inputs. The search is fine if I want to search for just one user input. But when I combine two or more of the inputs it returns All of both of them.

There are 4 user inputs but ive broken it down to two while i troubleshoot. If I use OR operators then there are some results but multiple search items get skewed, if I use the AND operator no results are displayed.
The Query currently looks like this: ("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Vehicle v JOIN Test t ON v.vehicle_id = t.vehicle_id WHERE v.make LIKE '" + make + "' OR t.test_result LIKE '" + testResult + "'");

I fully expect this to be a simple solution but I cant get my head around it.

Thanks

```
    JTextField tf1 = new JTextField("Make:");
    tf1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,40));
    tf1.setEditable(true);
    tf1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent x) {
            tf1.setText("");
        } });               

    JTextField tf4 = new JTextField("Test Result");
    tf4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,40));
    tf4.setEditable(true);
    tf4.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent x) {
            tf4.setText("");
        } });   

    JButton bMake = new JButton("Results");
    bMake.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,40));
    bMake.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            String make = tf1.getText().trim(); 
            String model = tf2.getText().trim();
            String firstuse = tf3.getText().trim();
            String testResult = tf4.getText().trim();   
            try {
                Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:./data/Tables.db");
                Statement selectStat = c.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = selectStat.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Vehicle v JOIN Test t ON v.vehicle_id = t.vehicle_id WHERE v.make LIKE '" + make + "' OR t.test_result LIKE '" + testResult + "'");
                dtm.setRowCount(0);
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                int ID = rs.getInt("vehicle_ID");
                String make_ = rs.getString("make");
                String model_ = rs.getString("model");
                String colour = rs.getString("colour");
                String fuel = rs.getString("fuel_type");
                String cylinder = rs.getString("cylinder_capacity");
                String use = rs.getString("first_use");
                int test_id = rs.getInt("test_id");
                String test_type = rs.getString("test_type");
                String test_class = rs.getString("test_class");
                String test_date = rs.getString("test_date");
                // int test_mileage = rs.getInt(test_id)
                String test_result = rs.getString("test_result");   
                String test_mileage = rs.getString("test_mileage");
                dtm.addRow(new Object[]{ID, make, model_, colour, fuel, cylinder, use,
                        test_id, test_type, test_class, test_date, test_result, test_mileage});     
                }   
        }    
            catch (SQLException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); } 
        }           
    });
```

Comment: Concatenating user inputs into SQL queries is a good way to introduce an SQL injection security vulnerability: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection in your application. At least use prepared statements.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Swing.  It is an SQL question. Separate your SQL from the Swing code so you can independently test the SQL code.